# framework 7 on click not working while navigation

Tags: javascript, ajax, performance, html-framework-7

I have used framework built-in `formToJSON()` to get the form values. I have used click event to console the value.

```
$$("#query-submit").on("click", function () {
    var queryForm = app.formToJSON("#query-form");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(queryForm));
});
```

It works fine when page loads first time. But if I changed navigation to other page and return back to first page.
On debug, I found click event is not working when I went back to form page.
Also found this warning in console.

[image]

What is wrong here.
**Note All pages were loaded via AJAX**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$$(document).on('click', '#query-submit', function(){
    // your code
});
```

Comment: what is the reason for the warning?